# Assign Variable Type Using Element From List(Of Type)

Tags: .net, vb.net

Let's say you have the three class's below: a, b and c.

I want to add these classes(not an instance of these classes) to a list of a generic type to be used later.

Is it possible to declare another variable using one of the elements of this list as the type?

As attempted below.

Where "obj" becomes an instance of what ever type "t" is.

I'm not sure what to title this question so please feel free to edit for clarity.

```
Class a
    Public gI As String
End Class

Class b
    Public gI As String
End Class

Class c
   Public gI As String
End Class

Class main
    Sub new()
        Dim types As New List(Of Type)
        types.Add(GetType(a))
        types.Add(GetType(b))
        types.Add(GetType(c))

        For Each t As Type In types
            Dim obj As GetType(t) 'I cannot seem to get this line to work
            Console.WriteLine(obj.GetType)
            'Output should be 
            'a
            'b
            'c  
        Next
    end sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim obj As GetType(t)
```

becomes

```
Dim obj As Object = t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(Nothing)
```

because since you have not defined an interface or base class there is no "type" that represents a, b, and c except Object.

for it to be an Instance, you have to instantiate it, so the code finds the default constructor and instantiates it

Comment: The type is the class though? He defined them as a,b,c

Comment: yes, i guess the question is, does he really need to just print the type name, or does he need to instantiate them?  (I posted my response before i saw you post outputting the type names)

Comment: true - I think we wanted just types so we didn't have to instantiate them, for w/e reason later down the road?

Comment: @DumpsterNinja i want "obj" to become an instance of the type of whatever element "t" is. The printing was arbitrary Thanks

Comment: awesome, then that code i posted should get you what you want.  obj will be an instance of the type.   just remember it expects you to have a null constructor;  if you ever change the constructor of A, B, C to have parameters in the constructor it will fail.   but if that code works for you please mark as answer :)

Comment: @DumpsterNinja depending on the use, if the list is created at some distance from where it is used, you might include a runtime reflection-based check requiring the types to have a parameter-less ctor.  Or, alternatively, you might require them to expose a specific `Shared` function that you could call to instantiate an object.  (Beware the performance implications of using reflection, it's usually quite slow, so don't use it in a tight loop.)

Answer (score 0):

Hey you have it already mostly.  You already are going GetType to populate the list.  You are now trying to GetType again?

Just iterate over your list and return the object directly - which is already.. a Type:

```
Public Module Module1

Class a
    Public gI As String
End Class

Class b
    Public gI As String
End Class

Class c
   Public gI As String
End Class

Public Sub Main()
    Dim types As New List(Of Type)
    types.Add(GetType(a))
    types.Add(GetType(b))
    types.Add(GetType(c))

    For Each t As Type In types
        Console.WriteLine(t)
    Next
End Sub

End Module
```

Here's a picture w/ output:
[image]